# Is changing my refresh from 60Hz to 75Hz dangerous if my pc already has an interlaced option for such?

Tags: display, resolution, refresh-rate, aspect-ratio, deinterlace

My monitor has a 1920x1080 at 60Hz although, I was wondering if I could push that to 75Hz at at lower resolution like 1280x720 or 1024x576 because my monitor already has a 75Hz option although, it is interlaced so I was wondering if I could do it without the interlacing to get a 16:9 aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mainly relates to television rather than computer graphics, but 'Interlaced' is actually a 'cheaper' option - it means the scan takes two passes to complete the screen redraw - it draws the even-numbered lines in one pass & the odd-numbered in the next. 'Progressive' is the more complete option, which fills the screen top to bottom with each pass.

In effect 75Hz interlaced is doing less work than 60Hz progressive. It's taking two passes to fill the screen, so though you won't really be able to see it, it's only fully updating the image at 37.5 Hz.

Stick to 60. On an LCD screen with only "Full HD" resolution, that's sufficient.

For televisions, this is what's referred to by 720p, 720i, or 1080p, 1080i etc.

Comment: Then how come when I use the 75Hz option, I achieve more fps than when I use 60Hz?

Comment: You can use the higher refresh rate if you wish

Comment: The fps value in a game is not actually related to how well your screen can draw the information sent to it. It is, however, related to the screen resolution. 720i is a lot faster to calculate for than 1080p. @John - sure you can use the higher rate… but it's actually slower, not faster, because of the interleaving. It's also a lower resolution so it can manage to achieve that rate. It's not an 'improvement' it's a saving.

Comment: Games may be affected but regular apps don't see much difference in the display rate. For that, native resolution works perfectly

Comment: @John - regular 'desktop 2D' apps may only be refreshing at 2 or 3 fps. I'm not seeing the relevance of your comments.